# Anyway to making both Publickey and Privatekey with the given data?

Tags: java, php, android, authentication, rsa

I'm university student and have got a task to do the secure under the requirement "Don't store the whole secret on the server but still able to validate". My scheme is making an RSA key pair on the client, store the public key on the server and throw away the private key. When authentication needed, Server will encrypt some string with stored private key, let the Client **make a same key again and decrypt it with the key** and send back to server.

(Maybe) Explained as follow

> Some data ----**Processing**----> RSA-1024(or better) PrivateKey + PublicKey

- Private key **have to be generated and was the same every time**
- Public key have to be stored on the server **and compatible with given private key**

The problem is the processing, I want to let the Client generate the same key for every time I want (could use hashed of some data as an input) but I don't know how to config this. Both Private and Public key is still need to compatible with each other.

Strong private key in the device make the application can't be used if user change the device.

I tried to research all along but most says that I have to save the key on the device otherwise generate a new key every time which is not my aiming.

I have already talk to my Project Teacher and this scheme is passed. but **I still need more comments if this scheme has any error** or if there are any suggestion from you. I'm still wondering if this scheme is better than storing hashed data and keep it for validation or not.

My scheme have to works on Android Client and PHP Server.

Highly thank you for reading and sorry If there is any error in this thread. I'm quite new here but this time I'm quite sure that this thread isn't duplicated.

Comment: That's not how public-key encryption works. You encode with the public key and decode with the private key, or vice versa. It doesn't work if you throw one of them away. And you can't get one from the other, that defeats the whole purpose.

Comment: Read [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography)

Comment: And if you want to ask questions about design of crypto systems, crypto.stackexchange.com would be a better place than SO. Come here when you have actual code that you need help with, not design questions ;like this.

Comment: Actually, you're not supposed to encipher with the private key, because there's a really good chance you'll make your private key vulnerable.
https://rdist.root.org/2008/12/04/more-dangers-of-amateur-crypto/

Comment: You probably mean that the user types in a password which is used to seed a CSPRNG which is then used to generate an RSA key pair on the fly. The client would sent the public key to the server when registering the account. On login, the client could regenerate the RSA private key and sign something like the current time. The server could use the stored public key to verify the current time. That's something that could be done (with a lot of work), but I don't see how this is better than using proper authentication through hashing (PBKDF2, bcrypt, scrypt or Argon2).

Comment: See more: [How to securely hash passwords?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/211/45523)

Comment: Thanks for all comments. I have read it all and will find out some algorithm that suits me.